# Tensorflow Shuffle Batch Non Deterministic

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get deterministic behaviour from `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`. I could, instead, use `tf.train.batch()` which works fine (always the same order of elements), but I need to get examples from multiple tf-records and so I am stuck with `shuffle_batch()`.

I am using:

```
random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
tf.set_random_seed(0)
data_entries = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [data], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=1, capacity=512,
    seed=57, min_after_dequeue=32)
```

But every time I restart my script I get slightly different results (not completely different, but about 20% of the elements are in the wrong order).
Is there anything I am missing?

Edit: Solved it! See my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

First the reason shuffle_batch is non deterministic:

- The time until I request a batch is inherently random.
- In that time, a random number of tensors are available.
- Tensorflow calls a shuffle operation that is seeded but depending on the number of items, it will return a different order.

So no matter the seeding, the order is always different *unless* the number of elements is constant. So the solution is to keep the number of elements constant, but how we do it?

By setting `capacity=min_after_dequeue+batch_size`. This will force Tensorflow to fill up the queue until it reaches full capacity before dequeuing an item. Therefore, at the time of the shuffle operation, we have `capacity` many items which is a constant number.

So why are we doing this? Because one tf.record contains many examples but we want examples from multiple tf.records. With a normal batch we would first get all the examples of one record and then of the next one. This also means we should set `min_after_dequeue` to something larger than the number of items in one tf.record. In my example, I have 50 examples in one file so I set `min_after_dequeue=2048`.

Alternatively, we can also shuffle the examples before creating the tf.records, but this was not possible for me because I read tf.records from multiple directories (each with their own dataset).

Last Note: You should also use a batch size of 1 to be super save.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood something, but you can collect multiple tf-records in a queue with `tf.train.string_input_producer()`, then read the examples into tensors and finally use `tf.train.batch()`.

Take a look at [CIFAR-10 input](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py).

Comment: That doesn't work for me because it would read the contents of one tf_record first. Given that I have 50 examples per record I would always get those 50 examples but I want 50 examples from multiple tf_records. 
But I solved it now anyway - see above. Alternatively, I would have to shuffle the examples before creating the tf-records.